# Android Sliding Menu by Jeremy Feinstein

Tags: android

I cloned repo with Android Sliding Menu example from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. I successfully built library. But while building example project I got four same error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'viewBehind' in package 'com.slidingmenu.example'
```

Can anybody explain what this error means and what should I do to get this bug fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project prefrences. Under android you can see the library the project uses. Delete the one with an "x" and add the right library to the example.

Comment: Right library is added to project. By the way I'm using Intellij Idea